# Cannot use for loop to render two pdf with dompdf

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

Those PDFs are the same code and same format and the difference is the text language. It can render first PDF, but do not success on second PDF. I have a test on the dompdf with the following code which cause error 500. Also, I use the **Codeigniter** framework. Is that a bug of dompdf or my bug?

```
$lang_array = array("chi","eng");
$i = 0;
foreach($lang_array as $lang)
{
    $html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>M</body></html>";
    $this->dompdf->load_html($html);
    $this->dompdf->set_paper("A4", 'portrait');
    $this->dompdf->render();
    $output = $this->dompdf->output();
    file_put_contents($i.".pdf", $output);
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've seen you can't reuse the existing dompdf instance. Once a render has been done there's a lot of internal objects created that dompdf currently doesn't have a method of removing.

But that's not to say you can't render more than one document. You'll just have to re-instantiate dompdf. Typically you would do something like the following:

```
foreach ($htmldocs as $index => $html) {
  $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
  $dompdf->load_html($html);
  $dompdf->render();
  $output = $dompdf->output();
  file_put_contents($index . '.pdf', $output);
  unset($dompdf);
}
```

I've found in the past that you can achieve better performance by isolating the dompdf rendering component to a separate script and spawning a new process to perform the render. So your `foreach` would be something like:

```
foreach ($htmldocs as $index => $html) {
  file_put_contents($index . '.html', $html);
  exec('php dompdf.php ' . $index . '.html');
}
```

And dompdf.php would be something like:

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html_file($argv[1]);
$dompdf->render();
file_put_contents(str_replace('.html', '.pdf', $argv[1]), $dompdf->output());
```

---

How you accomplish this in Codeigniter depends on your implementation. You're referencing a class property (from the controller instance, perhaps?) so I suspect you may have to rewrite things a bit. If you add more of your implementation details we can guide you further.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>";
 $html .= "<div>DATA 1 (chi)</div>"; 
 $html .= "<div>DATA 1 (eng)</div>";
 $html .= "</body></html>";

 $this->dompdf->load_html($html)
 $dompdf->dompdf->set_paper("A4", 'portrait');
 $dompdf->render();
 $dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");
```

> Try to put content on both div which fill whole A4 page. This separate the pdf into two parts. Page-1 and page-2

Comment: i need to export **2** PDF not one.

Comment: You min 2 different windows of pdf